# Java constructor with generic arguments implementing an interface

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to extend a generic class in such a way that the child class can be constructed in 2 ways:

- The objects passed in the constructor have to extend the interface `DistinguishableItem`
- The objects don't extend the above interface, but provide an `ItemDistinguisher` as an additional argument.

I have tried to implement it like this:

```
public class AdvancedAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>{
    protected ItemDistinguisher distinguisher = null;

    public interface DistinguishableItem{
        boolean isDivider();
    }
    public interface ItemDistinguisher{
        boolean isDivider();
    }

    public AdvancedAdapter(Context context, int itemResource, T[] objects, ItemDistinguisher dist) {
        super(context, itemResource, objects);
        this.distinguisher = dist;
    }
    public <T extends DistinguishableItem> AdvancedAdapter(Context context, int itemResource, T[] objects) {
        super(context, itemResource, objects);
    }
}
```

I get a weird error on second constructor saying that the method `super(...)` cannot be resolved. This is the only way i can think of to do this sort of thing. Naturally I would try to move the `<T extends DistinguishableItem>` into the declaration of the class, but if i did that the first constructor would fail becasue the `objects` wouldn't extend the required interface.

Is this possible in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code confuse class T for AdvancedAdapter and ArrayAdapter and the class of parameters objects in the second constructor

You can rewrite your method to see it:

```
public <X  extends DistinguishableItem> AdvancedAdapter(Context context, int itemResource, X[] objects)
```

And the error is always the same and more clear:

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<T>(Context, int, X[]) is undefined
```

Because there is no relation between T and X class

You can cast, but it is unsafe:

```
    super(context, itemResource, (T[]) objects);
```

You could test if X is a subclass of T, and if not, throw an exception.